# How can I set points on google maps, using php and locations from database?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a database and a table named markers. In this table there are the coordinates of specific locations that I want to mark on a map using Google maps. I can set the map on my website but when I try to use php to mark the locations I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>X</title>

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style type="text/css">
            #map {
                width:  100%;
                height: 700px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyASm3CwaK9qtcZEWYa-iQwHaGi3gcosAJc&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);


                 function init() {
                     var mapOptions = {                                    
                    zoom: 15,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.2118735,-8.4240415,16);
                    styles: [   {featureType:"administrative",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"on"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:20}]},  {featureType:"road",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"on"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:40}]},    {featureType:"water",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"on"},{saturation:-10},{lightness:30}]},    {featureType:"landscape.man_made",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"simplified"},{saturation:-60},{lightness:10}]},   {featureType:"landscape.natural",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"simplified"},{saturation:-60},{lightness:60}]},    {featureType:"poi",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"off"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:60}]},    {featureType:"transit",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"off"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:60}]}]
                };

                var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);   
                 }
                });


        </script>

  </head>
<?php
    include ('headbar.php');
    require ('conexao.php');
    $getpoints = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers");
    if(!$result = $con->query($getpoints)){die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');
      } else {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo 'var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng('.$row[lat].', '.$row[lng].'); 
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng1, map: map, title:"'.$row[name].'"});';
    }
  }
?>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, and I would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: I fear that you're mixing MySQL APIs. `mysql_query` + `$con->query`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed everything to mysql, and now its connecting to the database and I can echo the data, but it is still not marking the locations on the map. Any tips?

Comment: @Almeida If you want to put a code snippets in a question/answer your snippet must be runnable. Your HTML has server side tags `<?php>` it is not a runnable code snippet. Just format it as a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store the PHP values into a javascript array

At the top of your page:

```
require ('conexao.php');
$points = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers");

if(!$result){
     die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');
} else {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $points[] = array('lat' => $row['lat'], 'lng' => $row['lng'], 'name' => $row['name']);
    }
}


<script type="text/javascript">
     var points = <?php echo json_encode($points); ?>;
     $(document).ready(function(){
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

             function init() {
                 var mapOptions = {                                    
                     zoom: 15,
                     center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.2118735,-8.4240415,16),
                     styles: [  {featureType:"administrative",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"on"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:20}]},  {featureType:"road",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"on"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:40}]},    {featureType:"water",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"on"},{saturation:-10},{lightness:30}]},    {featureType:"landscape.man_made",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"simplified"},{saturation:-60},{lightness:10}]},   {featureType:"landscape.natural",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"simplified"},{saturation:-60},{lightness:60}]},    {featureType:"poi",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"off"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:60}]},    {featureType:"transit",elementType:"all",stylers:[{visibility:"off"},{saturation:-100},{lightness:60}]}]
                 };
                 var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
                 var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);   

                  for (var i=0,l=points.length;i<l;i++) {
                      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat, points[i].lng); 
                      var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng, map: map, title:points[i].name});
                  }
             }                 
      });


</script>
```

Comment: I tried to use the code you send me and its giving me many errors about semicolons parenthesis. For example the line "var points = <?php echo json_encode($points); ?>; "

Comment: No. It has all the data from the database.

Comment: 0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'lat' => string '40.198254' (length=9)
      'lng' => string '-8.407954' (length=9)
      'name' => string 'Bairro Norton de Matos' (length=22)

Comment: It is still giving me the same error. The semicolon, on the line "var points = <?php echo json_encode($points); ?>;"

Comment: Do you have any idea what this is about? The thing is, I have the data in an array, but the map is not showing, and somehow I cant put the markers with the locations I have on the array.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you may have some bad data encoding in your database. What happens if you remove the `name` key from the array?

Comment: I removed the semicolon from the place I said and now its telling me myLatlng1 is not defined. The map is now appearing btw, but still without the markers.

Comment: I figured out the error you corrected, but it was still giving me the error of the semicolon on the line I said. So I removed it, my map is now showing up, i'm not getting any errors but the markers are not there. I can't figure out what's the problem with the code now.

Comment: As you said, there was a problem with the enconding in my database. Now it is not giving me the semicolon error. The data is entering correctly into the variable. But it is still not marking the locations on the map.

Comment: Thank you so much for the patience. It worked. And sorry for the obsessive questions.